# Does this Desk draft seem sufficently sturdy

Tags: pipe, wooden-furniture, steel, desk

I am trying to design a 96" x 25" desk using 1.5" thick butcher block and 3/4" galvanized steel pipe. I would be using this as a craft desk, to hold a 50lbs pc, and a small flatscreeen tv.
[image: Image of the draft]
[image]

The idea is to have 6 legs offset 3" from all sides of the butcherblock, attached to the block with steel flanges screwed into the wood, and to use the same piped fitted between the legs and held in place with Tee and Cross fittings.
[image: Image showing offset of pipes from edges]

My main concern is the area labeled with the question mark. Would it be better to have 2 of the 23" bars, one above and one below the Cross fitting for the 32" bars or would it be better to double the amount of 32" bars to go above and below the fitting for the 23" bar. Illustrated below.
[image: Example of above suggestion]

For context I previously build a desk with the dimensions 72" x 32" using the same type of design without doubling the racking bars.

The original desk has 2 front legs and 3 back legs spaced 3" each side of the butcher block and is secured to the butcher block with galvanized flanges screwed into the wood. This desk has bars between the legs to prevent racking These bars are attached to the legs with Tee and Cross fittings. This original desk borders on immovable as far as racking or sagging goes.

Comment: I don't see any diagonal, X, or sheet bracing. That's usually a bad sign.

Comment: with 8 legs it will have plenty of vertical rigidity.  horizontally it may be a little weak but that really depends on how well the pipe flanges are attached to the underside and how tight the tees are

Comment: also it I'm reading you pipe scheme right it will be impossible to complete the eights joint, because you can't make a loop out of threaded pipe. (the cheat code  to use a union or a left handed thread somewhere)

Comment: I'm not sure about what's going on with this design. Are there 4 legs at the back and 2 out front? Is the only bracing for the front legs coming from straight back? And A versus B? These are hypothetical bracing configurations from the back row of legs? Galvanized doesn't matter. Is this schedule 40 pipe?

Comment: Some guy wires for diagonal bracing might be worth considering. But since those could be added later I'd say try it and see. As @Jasen noted, as drawn it can't all be threaded connections.

Comment: Ecnerwal -
Diagonal is possible but may require a redesign. I will look into it.

Comment: Keshlam - 
Wire is actually something I had not thought of using. III will look into that as well. Thankfully none off this is threaded soo we should be good in regards to threading issues.

Comment: Jasen - 
Pipe is not threaded, just a flat end, I should have mentioned all connections are bolt in and will be tightened with an impact wrench like the desk I made previously.

Comment: popham -
4 Legs in back, 2 in front. The two front legs will be connected to each other with a pipe that goes along the front attached with a tee on each leg and 2 tees and 2 flanges to anchor the middle point to the wood.

Pipe is schedule 40.

And yes those are hypothetical configurations for the back side bracing.

Comment: Personally, I think threaded pipe would be sturdier than bolted connections.